# Docker running app is displayed only in docker internal ip address, NOT localhost

Tags: docker

I have a simple flask app to learn docker and docker-compose.

After run docker container, I expected to see app on http://127.0.0.1:5001, But it's only available on http://172.18.0.2:5001 which is internal docker ip address.

Here is log

```
web  |  * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
web  |  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5001
web  |  * Running on http://172.18.0.2:5001
web  | Press CTRL+C to quit
web  |  * Restarting with stat
web  |  * Debugger is active!
web  |  * Debugger PIN: 359-467-367
```

Here is docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build: ./services/web
    container_name: web
    command: python manage.py run -h 0.0.0.0
    volumes:
      - ./services/web/:/usr/src/app/
    ports:
      - 5001:5000
    environment:
      - FLASK_APP=project/__init__.py
      - FLASK_DEBUG=1
      - FLASK_RUN_PORT=5001
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.11.3-slim-buster

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /usr/src/app/
```

**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return jsonify(hello="world")
```

I only can see {"hello":"world"} on http://172.18.0.2:5001, NOT on http://127.0.0.1:5001. Please educate me. Thaks in advance.

Comment: Because you are publishing the wrong port to your host, in your docker compose file: `- 5001:5000` should be `- 5001:5001`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I used same port number (5001) and now I can see the json message ({ "hello" :"world"}) in localhost:5001 as well. Can you please elaborate more what just happened?

Comment: The syntax of items in the `ports` list is `<host port>:<container port>`. Your Flask service is listening on port 5001 (because you're setting `FLASK_RUN_PORT`), so the right-hand side of the `ports` entry must *always* be `5001`. The left-hand side (the host port) can be whatever you want.

Comment: Wow! When I set ports: - 5005:5001 in docker-compose.yaml, I can see the json messege "localhost:5005" and "172.18.0.2:5001". Something magical things are happening in docker ports... What will be good materials for this topics regarding docker ports?

Comment: Finally I got the concept of ports mapping I think. 8080:5001 means that localhost's port 8080 is binding to docker_container's app which is using docker port 5001. Port mapping  is same concept of volume mappings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already know Docker have Networking system build in and here you are using the

```
command: python manage.py run -h 0.0.0.0
```

in your docker swarm .
so you are just hosting the app on the 0.0.0.0 which is basically your docker IP so you should see the app running in your docker_ip:port the port here your are using in docker is 5001 for your flask

and as you can see the hosted app can be accessed through *172.18.0.2:5001* which is your docker ip now , the docker didn't do much until now
the

```
-h 0.0.0.0
```

was the main reason for this behavior check out here [flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/quickstart/#a-minimal-application)

now in your docker-swarm.yml the issue is

```
ports:
      - 5001:5000
```

here basically the format is this

```
- host_machine_port : container_port
```

the wrong part is you are exposing the port 5000 which is not used by anything to your host machine's port 5001

for your linking purpose you can link to any available host_machine_port to your container exposed port your flask is using 5001 so the second part is going to be 5001 and for easy to remember the host_machine_port you can use is 5001

```
- 5001:5001
```

so now you will be able to use this correctly so to sum it up

```
command: python -m flask --app manage run
    volumes:
      - ./services/web/:/usr/src/app/
    ports:
      - 5001:5001
```

add this to your manage.py file

```
if __name__ == ‘__main__’:
   app.run(debug=True, port=5001)
```

from your container you can go to
**http://127.0.0.1:5001**

and from your host you can go to
**http://host_ip:5001**

and you will be good to go if any problem arises inform me

Comment: Thanks for your elaborated answer! Ports are difficult always...

Comment: @user5967613 finding open ports are kind of problematic but if you know how to its east the best way going to be netstat [windows](https://www.alphr.com/how-to-check-which-ports-open-windows-10-pc/),  [linux](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-check-open-ports-in-linux-using-the-cli/)